# How to run my PayPal code for 'INR' currency in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal, ionic3

I am working in my Ionic App and I have added the PayPal native plugin in my app but when I have added the 'INR' currency in PayPal code it is not opening in the real device and when I changed the currency to 'USD' it is opening.

This is my **checkout.ts**:

```
 makepaymentp()
  {
    //console.log("Payment");
    this.PayPalMobile.init({
      PayPalEnvironmentProduction: 'YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID',
      PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: '-----------------------------',
    }).then(() => {
      // Environments: PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork, PayPalEnvironmentSandbox, PayPalEnvironmentProduction
      this.PayPalMobile.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({
        // Only needed if you get an "Internal Service Error" after PayPal login!
        //payPalShippingAddressOption: 2 // PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal
      })).then(() => {
        let payment = new PayPalPayment(this.totalpricec, 'INR', 'Description', 'sale');
        this.PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then(() => {
          // Successfully paid

          // Example sandbox response
          //
          // {
          //   "client": {
          //     "environment": "sandbox",
          //     "product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK",
          //     "paypal_sdk_version": "2.16.0",
          //     "platform": "iOS"
          //   },
          //   "response_type": "payment",
          //   "response": {
          //     "id": "PAY-1AB23456CD789012EF34GHIJ",
          //     "state": "approved",
          //     "create_time": "2016-10-03T13:33:33Z",
          //     "intent": "sale"
          //   }
          // }
        }, () => {
          // Error or render dialog closed without being successful
          console.log("Error or render dialog closed without being successful");
        });
      }, () => {
        // Error in configuration
        console.log("Error in configuration");
      });
    }, () => {
      // Error in initialization, maybe PayPal isn't supported or something else
      console.log("Error in initialization, maybe PayPal isn't supported or something");
    });
  }
```

I am running the app in my device and it is not running for the 'INR' and it is running for the 'USD'.

Can anyone help me how to run the code for 'INR' in PayPal in Ionic App.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are u fixed above issue?

Comment: @Kapilsoni. Not yet. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: No bro I am also facing same issue I am not understand what I do next do u have decided anything for above issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "scope": "https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks openid https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",
  "nonce": "2017-06-08T18:30:28ZCl54Q_OlDqP6-4D03sDT8wRiHjKrYlb5EH7Di0gRrds",
  "access_token": "Access-Token",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "app_id": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
  "expires_in": 32398
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh : i am also facing same issue where to right above code?